Closed Formula for maximal interval of existence of autonomous ODE
I just stumbled across the following theorem (https://jordanbell.info/LaTeX/mathematics/domainODE/domainODE.pdf) and was wondering about its validity and proof, as the author does not provide a reference. And it does seem like a very strong and useful result.
Assume we have an autonomous ODE:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x),\: x(0) = x_0
\end{equation*}
for a continuous, positive function $f:[x_0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$. (I assume that maybe local Lipschitz continuity was forgotten as an assumption here). Then, the endpoint $T$ maximal interval of existence $(-\infty, T)$ of the solution $x(t)$ is given by the formula:
\begin{equation*}
T:=\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{f(x)}
\end{equation*}
So I have three questions:

Is this result correct ?
Can it be extended to higher dimensional cases, i.e. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ ?
I would guess that the result holds analogously for strictly negative $f$. Now for example, if $f$ is positive for $x \in (0, x_1)$ and negative for $x \in (x_1, x_2)$, is it possible to extend a (maybe weaker) form of this result to functions $f$ switching signs ?


I think you need $f$ to be positive, not just nonnegative. I would guess that this proof proceeds by a $u$-sub of the form $dt = \frac{dx}{dt}^{-1}dx$.

Let $f:[x_0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be locally Lipschitz continuous, and let $x:[0,T)\to [x_0,\infty)$ be the solution (nonextendable to the right) of $x'(t)=f(x(t))$, $x(0)=x_0$. Since $f\ge 0$ the solution $x$ is nondecreasing. If $f$ has a zero $x_1 \in  [x_0,\infty)$, say, then $x(t) \le x_1$ (by uniqueness) and $T= \infty$. Thus we can assume $f > 0$ on $[x_0,\infty)$. Then $x(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to T)$: Otherwise $a:= \lim_{t \to T} x(t)$ exists. If $T= \infty$ we would have $f(a)=0$ (in contradiction to $f>0$) and if $T <  \infty$ we could extend $x$ to the right by a solution of the IVP $y'=f(y)$, $y(T)=a$.
Separation of variables now yields
$$
\int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \frac{1}{f(\xi)}d\xi = \int_0^t \frac{x'(s)}{f(x(s))}ds =t,
$$
and $t \to T$ shows
$$
\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(\xi)}d\xi =T.
$$
Note also that the maximal interval of existence is not $(-\infty,T)$. If $f>0$ the solution $x$ has to be strictly increasing, thus $x$ would leave the domain of $f$ for $t<0$.

Thank you that is very helpful !
